# Problem involved comparing two variance

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

> The body mass index () is a factor in assessing the health of a person. The data given are
> the  for random samples of 18 women and 20 men selected in a town. Assume that the 
> for such women are normally distributed with variance 25, while the  for such men are
> normally distributed with the variance of 16.
> Construct a 96% confidence interval for the difference between the mean  of the
> women and men in the town. Interpret your results.

The above is the Question given, from my understanding the variance given is the sample variance but which test should I use because I don't know whether the population variance is equal or unequal.

The question has provided a set of data but didn't mention it is population data or sample data and request to pick the data randomly from the dataset.

Comment: It looks like the problem is telling you the *population* variances of the BMIs for men and women, not the sample variances. If you really believe that the $25$ and $16$ correspond to sample variances, you could use them to perform the hypothesis test $H_0:\sigma_m^2= \sigma_f^2$ versus $H_a:\sigma_m^2\neq \sigma_f^2$. If you fail to reject $H_0$ then you should use a pooled variance in your construction of the confidence interval

Comment: It seems to me that this is a question about the confidence interval for the difference in means rather than a question about a test for population variances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for explaining why you're having trouble with this problem.

It is seems likely that the data given are for samples of 18 women and 20 men. If so, find the sample means $\bar X$ and $\bar Y$ for women and men, respectively. (Because population variances are given, there is no point in estimating them from sample data.)

The standard error for the difference $\bar X -\bar Y$ of sample means of women and men
is $$\mathrm{SE}=
\sqrt{\frac{\sigma_x^2}{n_x}+\frac{\sigma^2_y}{n_y}}=
\sqrt{\frac{25}{18}+\frac{16}{20}}.$$

So a **95**% confidence interval for $\mu_x - \mu_y$ is of the form
$$\bar X - \bar Y \pm 1.96\mathsf{SE}.$$

Can you find formulas similar to these in your text or class notes? For a 90% CI you would use a different
probability factor (instead of $1.96$) from standard normal tables.

Comment: Hi, so the variance of 25 and variance of 16 is population variance?

Comment: Yes. Question is long and wording seems a bit imprecise. (Almost like something from a Google translation.) However, based on "Assume that the  for such women are normally distributed with variance 25, while the  for such men are normally distributed with the variance of 16," it seems to me that those are _population_ variances.

Comment: Ohh okay thankss